# Segue not running

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I am using an if statement to run a segue. I have the if statement printing a message whenever it successfully runs. However, the segue is not running and I'm not sure why.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstField.delegate = self
    signUpButtonOutlet.isEnabled = false
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Check> = Check.fetchRequest()

    do {
        //go get the results
        let searchResults = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

        //I like to check the size of the returned results!
        print ("num of results = \(searchResults.count)")

        //You need to convert to NSManagedObject to use 'for' loops
        for check in searchResults as [NSManagedObject] {
            //get the Key Value pairs (although there may be a better way to do that...
            print("the value was\(check.value(forKey: "isLoggedIn"))")

            if (check.value(forKey: "isLoggedIn") != nil) {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loggedInTrue", sender: self)
                print("if statement ran")
            } 


        }


    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you tried to move your performSegue code to `viewDidAppear()` ??

Comment: just like @MrugeshTank said put your segue in the viewdidappear, you can't do segue on viewdidload

Comment: This is not the best way to do this, you should really store the logged in status in user defaults where you can check this variable in your app delegate on load up. Then display the correct controller

Comment: @Devster101 How would I go about that?

Comment: Ive added an answer explaining what I mean, hopefully it gets you on the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach for this would be to load the "loggedIn" controller from the appDelegate after checking if the user is already logged in.

So for example in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of the app delegate check the user defaults to see if the user if logged in

```
if UserDefaults.standard().bool(forKey: "logged_in") == true {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YOURSTORYBOARDNAME", bundle: nil)
    let loggedIn = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LOGGEDIN") as! UIViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = loggedIn
}
```

Obviously for this to work you need to set the loggedIn variable to true when the user actually logs in. Like so

```
UserDefaults.standard().setBool(true, forKey: "logged_in")
```

One thing you have to note is, change the YOURSTORYBOARDNAME to your actual storyboard and you'll also have to set the Identifier of that controller in the storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Store login status in `viewDidLoad` and performSegue in `viewDidAppear`. This hides the first ViewController if login status is true.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if (isloggedIn != false) {
        self.view.isHidden = true
    } else {
        self.view.isHidden = false
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    if (isloggedIn != false) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loggedInTrue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedInTrue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: why if we call the `performSegue` in `viewdidload` its called or not

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` `performSegue` won't be called. To call it in `viewDidLoad` we need to call it like `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedInTrue", sender: self)
}`

Comment: ha ha ha , already you have a answer, then why unnecessary increase the memory